# Must have a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Not entirely sure why I'm getting this error. Looked up and down the code for a few hours but I assuming it's a simple fix. Some of the code is copied over from a video and his works perfectly fine, so I don't know why it'd cause me any issues:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GoldPerSec : MonoBehaviour {


    public UnityEngine.UI.Text gpsDisplay();
    public Click click;
    public ItemManager[] items;


    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(AutoTick());
    }

    void Update() {
        gpsDisplay.text = GetGoldPerSec() + " gold/sec";
    }

    public int GetGoldPerSec(){
        int tick = 0;
        foreach (ItemManager item in items) {
            tick += item.count * item.tickValue;

        }
        return tick;
    }

    public void AutoGoldPerSec() {
        click.gold += GetGoldPerSec();
    }

    IEnumerator AutoTick() {
        while (true) {
            AutoGoldPerSec();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in

```
public UnityEngine.UI.Text gpsDisplay();
```

That is a method declaration, but there's no code inside the method.

It's unclear from the context what that should actually be. If it's a method, you can either implement it in this class, like

```
public UnityEngine.UI.Text gpsDisplay()
{
     return <something useful>;
}
```

Maybe it shall be a method and you want to implement it in a subclass, then mark the class as abstract:

```
public abstract class GoldPerSec : MonoBehaviour
```

Perhaps it should have been a field, then use

```
public UnityEngine.UI.Text gpsDisplay;
```

without the parentheses.

Comment: Either remove the () to make it a member variable or add a code block { } to actually make it a method.

Comment: @Grisgram: I was in the middle of adding that. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't mean to set gpsDisplay as a function, so that is what caused the issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

I got this error when I mistakenly added **;** before method body. Removing ; stops compiler error.
==My Code. Look **;** on very first line ===

```
      public string ReadPopMessage(String identifierOfElement, String elementKey);
        {

        //string elementID;
        elementID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(elementKey);
        Console.WriteLine("The value of" + elementKey + "is " + elementID);
        //MessageBox.Show(elementID);

        string strPopupText = oWD.FindElement(By.CssSelector(elementID)).Text;
        return elementID;

        }
```

Comment: While your answer does provide help for someone who might run into this issue with a similar situation, it does not apply to the original question given the code sample posted.